# Static files are served locally but not through nginx

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt, restify

I'm running a node.js API on a VPS, which is served by nginx on Ubuntu 13.04.

I'm using [restify](http://restify.com/) and serving static files like this:

```
server.get(
  /\/static\/?.*/,
  restify.serveStatic({
    directory: __dirname   // => /home/misha/rxviz-api
  })
);
```

Here is the relevant bits from nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name api.rxviz.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4010/;
    }
}
```

(full config is [here](https://gist.github.com/moroshko/80f957ad29ee2bf7d01199fca29b87b3#file-nginx-conf-L55-L72))

When running:

```
curl http://localhost:4010/static/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.json
```

on the VPS, I get the contents of `test.json`.

However, when navigating to:

```
http://api.rxviz.com/static/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.json
```

in a browser, I get 404.

nginx error logs show that `/opt/nginx/html/static/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.json` not found.

Why does nginx trying to access `test.json` in `/opt/nginx/html` rather than `/home/misha/rxviz-api`?

Few more points:

- `static` directory permissions are `drwxrwxr-x`
- I can access `http://api.rxviz.com/` in the browser successfully

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to be sure, as I can't test it, BUT..

I think you have a problem with the nginx settings:

```
location /static/ {
        alias /home/misha/rxviz-api/static/;
}
```

the /static is appended to the alias including the location part, so it's searches for `/home/misha/rxviz-api/static/static`
This is going to return 404 since there is no `static/` within `static/`

try to fix to:

```
location /static/ {
        alias /home/misha/rxviz-api/;
}
```

....
...

**and also I wanted just to mention.**
It's seems like your node server (using restify) is serving the content as you wanted (127.0.0.1:4010/static/... works as you say), 
BUT note that nginx is anyway not redirecting any of the /static calls into your node, so your node restify is unused.

why?

This section:

```
location /static/ {
        alias /home/misha/rxviz-api/static/;
}
```

tells nginx to NOT redirect those /static calls into your node service, and instead try to find and serve the file from the local path.

so if you want to use the restify... just remove this entire `location /static` part, and your node will serve those files too.

Comment: IFAIK, `root` is appending but `alias` isn't. (I tried `alias /home/misha/rxviz-api/;` anyway, but still 404).

Comment: I also tried to remove the `location /static/ { ... }` from the nginx config, but still 404.

Comment: did you restarted nginx daemon after editing or removing? because it's strange you removed the location block and you still get 404

Comment: try to use root instead of alias

Comment: also try to add error_log and access_log and see the log for more information. it still could be permissions issues as you suspected. https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/

Comment: I updated the question with the info from nginx error logs.